# Send a variable from one action to another in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Code in controller is

```
if params["type"] == "user"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to home_user_path, notice: "abc" }
  end
```

If I send variable with notice then work fine but I want to send with my own key like

```
format.html { redirect_to home_user_path, search: "abc" }
```

It doesn't recieve there

Comment: Do you want to send a URL param? If yes, do this `redirect_to home_user_path(search: "abc")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remember that **you're not "sending" a variable to another action**; you're *invoking* another action, and populating it with a variable (data):

---

**1. Instance Variable**

You can set an instance variable, which will then be available in the next action:

```
 def your_action
   @search = "abc"
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to home_user_path } #-> @search will be available in the other view
   end
 end
```

---

**2. Sessions**

You're currently trying to use `sessions` to populate the data:

```
def your_action
   redirect_to home_user_path, search: "abc"
end

#app/views/controller/your_action.html.erb
<%= flash[:search] %>
```

---

**3. URL**

Finally, you can set the value in the URL through your routes:

```
def your_action
   redirect_to home_user_path(search: "abc") #-> you'll probably need to set the user object too, judging from the route name
end
```

This should populate your route with some [`GET` request params](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure): `url.com/action?param=value`

---

The underpin of all of this, as mentioned, is that you're not sending a variable, you'll be initializing it in your *current* controller action, and then having the next action call it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with Ruby's optional braces: sometimes it's hard to see which method call something is being treated as an argument to.

Try this instead:

```
format.html { redirect_to home_user_path(search: "abc") }
```

this will redirect to home_user_path and set `params[:search]` to "abc".